# Can a Tiles definition extend a definition defined in an external jar using Spring TilesConfigurer?

Tags: spring, servlets, web-applications, tiles, weblogic-10.x

*Library Versions*: Spring 3.1.2, Tiles 2.2.2

Given the following setup, is it possible to extend and use a tile definition (i.e. "BaseTile" below) from an external (common) .jar?

**common.jar**

*/WEB-INF/common-tiles-defs.xml*

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="BaseTile" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/BaseTile.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**someproject.war**

*/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml*

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="ProjectTile" extends="BaseTile">
        <put-attribute name="content" expression="${someData}" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

*servlet-context.xml*

```
<beans:beans>

    <!-- Tiles Configuration: View Resolver -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass">
            <beans:value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Tiles Configuration: Definitions -->
    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>classpath:/WEB-INF/common-tiles-defs.xml</beans:value> <!-- from common.jar -->
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</beans:value>  <!-- from someproject.war -->
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

When I deploy the webapp (someproject.war), it appears to find the common-tiles-defs.xml inside common.jar, but when I try to render "ProjectTile", Tiles' DEBUG log outputs the following:

```
||20130716||15:20:36,074||||org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess||INFO ||Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
||20130716||15:20:37,589||||org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO||DEBUG||Resolve definition for child name='ProjectTile' extends='BaseTile'.
||20130716||15:20:37,590||||org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO||DEBUG||File null not found, continue
||20130716||15:20:37,591||||org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO||DEBUG||File null not found, continue
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.